# PHP calendar: Iterating through selected months?

Tags: php, calendar

been looking at this for a bit and now my eyes are crossed. :)

I have a calendar script that [I found on snipplr.com](http://snipplr.com/view/60198/calendar-generator-php/) It's pretty sweet. Props to the creators.  Now, I have two things I want to customize.

Right now, the calendar spits out 12 months, January to December. And also the week ends on Sunday (grrrr).  I am attempting to make it go from THIS MONTH, plus x number of months.  For example, it would display December, plus 5 more months, so Dec, Jan, Feb, March, April, May.

I can tell in the code it uses a $i iteration to get through the months and display the appropriate dates.  for($i=1;$i<=11;$i++)

SO, I tried changint it to this: for($i=$this_month;$i<=11;$i++)
$this_month of course being the date('m');

It does successfully display December, but no months after it. (Since it stops at 11). But if I up the 11 to another variable of $this_month+5, then the script doesnt know what months 13, 14 and 15 are.

Any help on this one?  Here is the entire script I have thusfar.

```
function days_in_month($month, $year) {
    if($month!=2) {
        if($month==9||$month==4||$month==6||$month==11)
            return 30;
        else
            return 31;
    }
    else
        return $year%4==""&&$year%100!="" ? 29 : 28;
}

global $months;
$months = array(0 => 'January', 1 => 'February', 2 => 'March', 3 => 'April', 4 => 'May', 5 => 'June', 6 => 'July', 7 => 'August', 8 => 'September', 9 => 'October', 10 => 'November', 11 => 'December');
$days = array(0 => 'Monday', 1 => 'Tuesday', 2 => 'Wednesday', 3 => 'Thursday', 4 => 'Friday', 5 => 'Saturday', 6 => 'Sunday');

function render_calendar($this_year = null) {
    if($this_year==null)
        $this_month = date('m')-1;
        $first = strtotime(date('m'));
        $last = strtotime("+6 months", $this_month);
        $this_year = date('Y');

    $day_of_the_month = date('N', strtotime('1 January '.$this_year));
    for($i=$this_month;$i<=12;$i++) {

//      echo $i;
//      if ($i==12) {
//          $i = 0;
//      }
        echo $i;
        echo "<table>
            <caption>".$GLOBALS['months'][$i]."</caption>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Sun</th>
                    <th>Mon</th>
                    <th>Tue</th>
                    <th>Wed</th>
                    <th>Thu</th>
                    <th>Fri</th>
                    <th>Sat</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>";
        for($n=1;$n<$day_of_the_month;$n++)
            echo "<td></td>\n";
        $days = days_in_month($i+1, $this_year);
        $day = 0;       
        while($day<$days) {
            if($day_of_the_month==8) {
                echo ($day == 0 ? "" : "</tr>\n") . "<tr>\n";
                $day_of_the_month = 1;
            }
            echo "<td style=\"border: 1px solid red;\">" . ($day+1) . "</td>\n";
            $day_of_the_month++;
            $day++;
        }
        echo "</tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this for your loop:

```
for($i=$this_month;$i<=$this_month+5;$i++) {
    // create a variable to hold the proper month index
    $currentMonth = $i;
    if ($i>11) {
        $currentMonth -= 12;
    }
    // now replace all references to the $i index with $currentMonth
    ...
}
```

Comment: Beautiful sir! Exactly what I was looking for. So although the $i variable may get to 15, 16, 17, you are setting the currentMonth BACK by subtracting 12 from it... brilliant....    Now on to making this a Sun to Sat calendar instead of Mon to Sun!   Thanks again!